# Access is Denied Error in Sitecore 9.1 Update 1 installing

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

All I am Getting following error when I am trying to `Install Sitecore 9.1 update 1`.

```
> This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied at
> \WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1
> & Sentry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
```

[image: nstalling]

Comment: provide full permission to your instance

Comment: Provide full access to your resource folder ... where you have all the set up files.